# Yii Date picker is not working

Tags: datepicker, yii2

I am using default datepicker in yii. I am following steps as below.

Downloaded the datepicker plugin by cmd. 
I have used this code into views,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'dob')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
                        'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy'
                        ]);
                     ?>
```

But, that plugin is not getting applied on the field. It looks like a normal text field.

Am I missing something?

Or

Do I need to add some other files to acheive that?

Comment: does the plugin need to be configured with Yii?

Comment: *"Downloaded the datepicker plugin by cmd. Then download it into web/assets folder."* - what you mean by that ? Did you use composer ?

Comment: @yasky. Configured Means. I didn't do anything. What to do?

Comment: @Tony. I have remove that line. I have downloaded by composer

Comment: any browser console errors ?

Comment: No error at all. Datepicker functions doesn't apply.

Comment: Do you need to have it in any of the config files as a plugin?

Comment: Do you have *jquery-ui.js* script on your page ? and *datepicker* initialization ? the widget must add them

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't used `use yii\jui\DatePicker;` in your form.php

```
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
<?= $form->field($model, 'from_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
    //'language' => 'ru',
    'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy',
    ]) ?>
```

Comment: In Your Model have you tried this [['from_date', 'to_date'], 'safe'], you have to put your datepicker field in safe state

Comment: could you please explain what type of error is this? Just copy paste the error so that i can have an idea of the error

Comment: It has no error. Calendar doesn't open on. It act like a textbox. not a date

Comment: In your gridview please try this                                                            use yii\jui\DatePicker;
                [
                'attribute' => 'from_date',
                'value' => 'from_date',
                'filter' => DatePicker::widget([ 'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy']),
                'format' => 'html',
                 ],                                                                                            hope this works

Comment: in your index.php add this:      use yii\jui\DatePicker;                               and inside the index.php there is a gridview. In gridview add:                 [ 'attribute' => 'from_date',                                                               'value' => 'from_date',                                                                       'filter' => DatePicker::widget([ 'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy']),     'format' => 'html', ],

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which plugin you have downloaded. So i am sending you stepwise procedure from scratch.

```
First download the plugin via cmd through `require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui` this command.

Place the downloaded folder in your `vendor/yiisoft` directory.

Then in your view file :

use yii\jui\DatePicker;

<?= $form->field($model, 'expiry')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-M-dd',
        'clientOptions' => [

        'changeMonth' => true,
        'yearRange' => '1996:2099',
        'changeYear' => true
        ],
    ]) ?>

Hope this will work for you.
```